# Request to Gemini API won't go in skaffold container

Tags: typescript, express, skaffold, google-gemini

I am trying to send a request to Google's Gemini API in an express server that is containerized.

```
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";

const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.GEMINI_API_KEY!);

async function run() {
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-pro" });

  const prompt = "Write a story about a magic backpack.";

  const result = await model.generateContent(prompt);
  const response = await result.response;
  const text = response.text();
  console.log(text);
}

export default run;
```

Whenever I call this function in `index.ts` after calling `app.listen()` it throws an error saying fetch failed which looks something like this

```
TypeError: fetch failed
[tests]     at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11731:11)
[tests]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[tests]     at makeRequest (/app/node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:240:20)
[tests]     at generateContent (/app/node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:614:22)
[tests] [ERROR] 07:42:56 Error: [GoogleGenerativeAI Error]: Error fetching from https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1/models/gemini-pro:generateContent: fetch failed
```

I tried doing the same in a new application which is not containerized and it worked (both javascript and typescript). What is happening here and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the HTTP Status Code and response body? There are many possibilities. Edit your question with details on the error.